# TouchJSON How to make a table populated with json clickable?

Tags: iphone, json

I am a total newbie on iOS development. After numerous tries; with lots of sample codes I managed to parse a json string from my server and able to display the results in a dynamic tableview. My problem is I cannot make the cells clickable so they would pass the id and the label to another view where another json parse will be performed to display the details of the row.

Below is my code:

```
#import "jsonviewcontroller.h"
#import "CJSONDeserializer.h"
#import "Otel_ItemViewController.h"

@implementation jsonviewcontroller


@synthesize tableview;
@synthesize rows;

- (void)dealloc {
    [rows release];
    [tableview release];
    [super dealloc];

}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [rows count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    NSDictionary *dict = [rows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"C_NAME"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"CAT_ID"];


    return cell;
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://zskript.net/categories.php"];
    NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSLog(jsonreturn); // Look at the console and you can see what the restults are

    NSData *jsonData = [jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
    NSError *error = nil;

    // In "real" code you should surround this with try and catch
    NSDictionary * dict = [[[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error] retain];
    if (dict)
    {
        rows = [dict objectForKey:@"users"];
    }

    NSLog(@"Array: %@",rows);


    [jsonreturn release];
}

// Do some customisation of our new view when a table item has been selected
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure we're referring to the correct segue
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSelectedMovie"]) {

        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        Otel_ItemViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // get the selected index
        NSInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableview indexPathForSelectedRow] row];

        // Pass the name and index of our film
        [vc setSelectedItem:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [rows objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]]];
        [vc setSelectedIndex:selectedIndex];
    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}



@end
```

And below is the view that will display the detail:

```
#import "Otel_ItemViewController.h"

@implementation Otel_ItemViewController

@synthesize selectedIndex, selectedItem;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [outputLabel setText:selectedItem];
    [outputText setText:selectedItem];
    [outputImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", selectedIndex]]];
}

@end
```

Currently, when I click the cells in the table, Although I have set it to push to the next view, nothing happens. Would someone please advise?

Here is the updated code.

My root view controller:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [rows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    DetailViewController *controller = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    controller.CATNAME = [dict objectForKey:@"C_NAME"];
    controller.CATNUMBER = [dict objectForKey:@"CAT_ID"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

And here is DetailViewController.h:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {


    NSString *CATNAME;
    NSInteger CATNUMBER;
    IBOutlet UILabel *labelId;
    IBOutlet UILabel *LabelName;

}

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger CATNUMBER;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *CATNAME;

@end
```

And DetailViewController.m:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize CATNAME, CATNUMBER;


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    LabelName.Text = CATNAME;
    labelId = CATNUMBER;
//    [LabelName setText:CATNAME];
//    [labelId setText:CATNUMBER];
}
```

Comment: Where is the delegate method that handles the touch events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement this method

EDIT: Loading a new view

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [rows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    MyNewViewController *controller = [[MyNewViewController alloc] init];
    controller.C_NAME = [dict objectForKey:@"C_NAME"];
    controller.CAT_ID = [dict objectForKey:@"CAT_ID"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

In the code above I assume you are using a navigation controller (which is the easiest way to do what you want to be doing). Also I am assuming you have a class that inherits from `UIViewController` that you want to have displayed. I am also assuming that this class which I called `MyNewViewController` in my example has two members and properties called C_NAME and CAT_ID respectively.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
     labelName.Text = C_NAME;
     labelId = CAT_ID
}
```

The above my be incorrect as I am doing it out of memory. But the principal stays the same, if you passed the variables correctly it should work, you can have a look at my [blog](http://www.armandvanderwalt.co.za) it still needs some work done on it, but it has a nice beginners post and shows how to edit the text of the label. In the code above I am assuming your view contains two labels labelName and labelId respectfully.

In there you have access to what cell was selected and you can then define what needs to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response; but I am not sure how to implement this. Would you be kind enough to clarify with a bit of code please?

Comment: What should happen when a cell is clicked?

Comment: I want it to pass C_NAME and CAT_ID from the json onto next view as variables. at next view I will use C_NAME for the title of the view and will use CAT_ID to perform another query to get the detail of the record from database.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long with responding this time, was afk for a bit. See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks a lot Armand. Now when I click the row it goes to next view. it comes blank because I haven't set it up to use the variables to make the query yet. I guess I ll figure that out somehow. If it wouldn't be too much trouble can you give me a snippet so I can test and see if the variables do get passed on? perhaps displaying them with 2 labels. one for the name, the other for the cat_ID?

Comment: Thanks a lot. You've been great help.

Comment: ARMAND, I've implemented this but the view is still coming out black. Simulator doesn't crash, and it doesn't produce any errors.

Comment: I've edited my original post and added updated code. Do you see a mistake in the code? Do you suppose the problem is at the interface builder?

Comment: Thanks Armand. It was an issue with the interface builder. I fixed it.